# Link to a child route but have active class on parent route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a navbar item

```
{{#link-to 'customer'}}
```

When clicked I want it to route to `customer.details` route. I can currently achieve this by having the `customer` route redirect to `customer.details`. However, when within the `customer.details` the route, if I click the link-to in the nav it transitions to the `customer` route instead of sending it to `customer.details`. None of the route functions like `redirect`, `activate`, or before/after model, fire when transitioning up to a route chain.

The other option of

```
{{#link-to 'customer.details'}}
```

would mean that any other customer.routename would not inherit the active class.

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a redactor KerrickLong helped me out with this:

---

> Try having the redirect to customer.details live on the customer.index
>   route instead of directly on the customer route.
>
> Works perfectly!

Comment: Some example code on how you did this would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

My links were doing this on Ember 2.0, using the solution above from Goobi.

In my router I have:

```
this.route('event', {path: '/:eventShortName'}, function(){
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.route('new-article', {path: 'new-article'});
    this.route('page', {path: ':articleTitle'}, function(){
      this.route('data', {path: ':dataId'});
    });
  });
```

Whenever I visited a event.page.data, all the links in the navbar would be active.

Before fix:

```
{{#link-to 'event.page' article.articleURL class="nav-dynamic hidden-xs" tagName="li" href=false}}
   {{#link-to 'event.page' article.articleURL }}
      {{article.articleTitle}}
   {{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

After fix:

```
{{#link-to 'event.page.index' article.articleURL class="nav-dynamic hidden-xs" tagName="li" href=false}}
   {{#link-to 'event.page.index' article.articleURL }}
      {{article.articleTitle}}
   {{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

The functionality remains the same, now when visiting a data url no links are active.